# How to get back to the input prompt in an interactive python program and still be able to abort running operations

Tags: python, error-handling, signals, interactive

I wrote an interactive python program with more than 100 functions which do various computations I'm interested in.

The user enters a function name at the input prompt, which is then executed with results either displayed as a return value or as a side effect. I want to be able to abort long running functions, via a control C, without killing the program.

This part I've accomplished. For example, as shown below, if a control-C is entered while
function2(20) is running, anytime before it finishes, the function is aborted and the input prompt is displayed again.

However if I happen, by accident, to enter control-C at the input prompt, the program is killed. I don't want that to happen; rather I want to just return back to the input prompt. Since these two features are part of standard python interpreters, it should be possible to do what I want.

Here's a skeleton version of what I've done, called skeleton.

```
#!/Users/richard.gostanian/anaconda3/bin/python

import sys
import signal
import time

def trivial_function(n):
   return n

def function2(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
       print(i)
       time.sleep(1)
    return n

while True:
   entered2 = input("Enter function with arguments: ")
   entered=entered2.strip()   # remove preceding and trailing whitespace from entered2

   if entered == 'q':
      print()
      quit()
   elif entered == "":  # go back to the input prompt
      print()
      continue
   else:
      try:
        result=eval(entered)
        print("\n   {} = {} \n".format(entered,result))
        continue
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
           print()
           continue
```

Here is the output if you type control-C while function2(20) is running

```
Enter function: function2(20)
1
2
3
4
^C
Enter function:
```

And here is the output if you type control-C at the input prompt

```
Enter function: ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/richard/home/richard/bin/./skeleton", line 17, in <module>
    entered2 = input("Enter function: ")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt

bash >
```

How do I modify this to not kill the program in the second case?

Comment: Can you just catch any stray Control-C at the highest level, and put in a confirmation prompt before closing? Seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `try/except` around the entire loop body, not just the call to `eval()`.

```
while True:
    try:
        entered2 = input("Enter function with arguments: ")
        entered=entered2.strip()   # remove preceding and trailing whitespace from entered2
    
        if entered == 'q':
            print()
            quit()
        elif entered == "":  # go back to the input prompt
            print()
        else:
            result=eval(entered)
            print("\n   {} = {} \n".format(entered,result))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
```

You don't need all those `continue` statements. A loop automatically continues unless the `while` condition is false or you use `break` to get out. You only need to use `continue` if you want to skip over the rest of the loop body and start the next iteration, but there's nothing to skip over.